# Access the content of css files with Webpacker

Tags: css, webpack, webpacker

Using Webpacker I can load css files and they get output in the stylesheet pack files, but sometimes I'd like to access the CSS in these files from within javascript for use say in a WYSIWYG editor's config (specifying some extra styles for the `IFRAME`). The other option is to be able to access the public path of a css file loaded in like so:

```
import froala_style from '../../../css/froala.css'
```

My suspicion is that it's to do with the css loader that comes with Webpacker. Its job is to load the css and compile it out to a seperate file. I think that one can't have two css loaders at the same time? Could the answer be to apply filters to a custom loader so that it takes effect on only the file I'm wanting to load in as text or the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can override the existing loaders for a particular import like so:

```
import froala_style from '!css-loader!../../../css/froala.css'
```

Prepending the `!` overrides existing loaders allowing us to specify our own. In this example one can call `froala_style.toString()` to receive the contents of the CSS file.

For reference: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline